# F# - Need help converting this to use a threadpool

Tags: asynchronous, f#, threadpool

I am new to F# and I have frankensteined the code below from various examples I found online in an attempt to get a better understanding of how I can use it. Currently the code below reads in a list of machines from a file and pings each of the machines. I had to divide the initial array from the file up into a smaller arrays of 25 machines to control the number of concurrent actions otherwise it takes far to long to map out the list of machines. I would like be able to use a threadpool to manage the threads but I have not found a way to make it work. Any guidance would be great. I am not able to make this work:

```ml
let creatework  = FileLines|> Seq.map (fun elem -> ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(dowork), elem))
```

Here is the complete code:

```ml
open System.Threading
open System
open System.IO

let filePath = "c:\qa\machines.txt"

let FileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)

let count = FileLines.Length/25

type ProcessResult = { exitCode : int; stdout : string; stderr : string } 

let executeProcess (exe,cmdline) = 
    let psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(exe,cmdline) 
    psi.UseShellExecute <- false
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput <- true 
    psi.RedirectStandardError <- true 
    psi.CreateNoWindow <- true
    let p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi, EnableRaisingEvents = true) 
    let output = new System.Text.StringBuilder()
    let error = new System.Text.StringBuilder() 
    p.OutputDataReceived.Add(fun args -> output.AppendLine(args.Data)|> ignore) 
    p.ErrorDataReceived.Add(fun args -> error.AppendLine(args.Data) |> ignore) 
    p.BeginErrorReadLine() 
    p.BeginOutputReadLine()
    p.WaitForExit()
    { exitCode = p.ExitCode; stdout = output.ToString(); stderr = error.ToString() } 

let dowork machinename=
    async{
        let exeout = executeProcess(@"c:\windows\system32\ping.exe", "-n 1 " + machinename)
        let exelines = 
            if exeout.stdout.Contains("Reply from") then Console.WriteLine(machinename + " " + "REPLY")
            elif exeout.stdout.Contains("Request timed out.") then Console.WriteLine(machinename + " " + "RTO")
            elif exeout.stdout.Contains("Ping request could not find host") then Console.WriteLine(machinename + " " + "Unknown Host")
            else Console.WriteLine(machinename + " " + "ERROR")
        exelines
        }

printfn "%A" (System.DateTime.Now.ToString())

for i in 0..count do
    let x = i*25
    let y = if i = count then FileLines.Length-1 else (i+1)*25
    printfn "%s %d" "X equals: " x
    printfn "%s %d" "Y equals: " y
    let filesection = FileLines.[x..y]
    let creatework = filesection |> Seq.map dowork |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously|>ignore
    creatework

printfn "%A" (System.DateTime.Now.ToString())
printfn "finished"
```

UPDATE:
The code below works and provides a framework for what I want to do. The link that was referenced by Tomas Petricek did have the bits of code that made this work. I just had to figure which example was the right one. It is within 3 seconds of duplicate framework written in Java so I think I am headed in the right direction. I hope the example below will be useful to anyone else trying to thread out various executables in F#:

```ml
open System
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics

let filePath = "c:\qa\machines.txt"

let FileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)

type Process with
    static member AsyncStart psi =
        let proc = new Process(StartInfo = psi, EnableRaisingEvents = true)
        let asyncExit = Async.AwaitEvent proc.Exited
        async {
            proc.Start() |> ignore
            let! args = asyncExit
            return proc
        } 

let shellExecute(program : string, args : string) =
    let startInfo =
        new ProcessStartInfo(FileName = program, Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true)
    Process.AsyncStart(startInfo)

let dowork (machinename : string)=
    async{
        let nonbtstat = "NONE"
        use! pingout = shellExecute(@"c:\windows\system32\ping.exe", "-n 1 " + machinename)
        let pingRdToEnd = pingout.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        let pingresults =
            if pingRdToEnd.ToString().Contains("Reply from") then (machinename + " " + "REPLY")
            elif pingRdToEnd.ToString().Contains("Request timed out.") then (machinename + " " + "RTO")
            elif pingRdToEnd.ToString().Contains("Ping request could not find host") then (machinename + " " + "Unknown Host")
            else (machinename + " " + "PING_ERROR")
        if pingresults.ToString().Contains("REPLY") then
            use! nbtstatout = shellExecute(@"c:\windows\system32\nbtstat.exe", "-a " + machinename)
            let nbtstatRdToEnd = nbtstatout.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Split('\n')
            let nbtstatline = Array.tryFind(fun elem -> elem.ToString().Contains("<00>  UNIQUE      Registered")) nbtstatRdToEnd
            return Console.WriteLine(pingresults + nbtstatline.Value.ToString())
        else return Console.WriteLine(pingresults + " " + nonbtstat)
        }

printfn "%A" (System.DateTime.Now.ToString())

let creatework = FileLines |> Seq.map dowork |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously|>ignore
creatework

printfn "%A" (System.DateTime.Now.ToString())
printfn "finished"
```

Comment: Instead of shelling out to `ping.exe` have you considered using the [Ping Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) instead? With a little bit of work, you could integrate the `SendAsync` method and `PingCompleted` event into an F# async workflow...

Comment: The reason I have not done this is because running the ping is just for testing. My interest in F# is the ability to leverage multiple CPU's by running threads in parallel. The evironment I work in uses executables that are over 15 years old that cannot be updated and I would like to find a way to take advantage of the multiple cores while still remaining backwards compatible.

Answer (score 6):

The main problem with your code is that `executeProcess` is a synchronous function that takes a long time to run (it runs the `ping.exe` process and waits for its result). The general rule is that tasks in a thread pool should not block for a long time (because then they block thread pool threads, which means that the thread pool cannot efficiently schedule other work).

I think you can solve this quite easily by making `executeProcess` asynchronous. Instead of calling `WaitForExit` (which blocks), you can wait for the `Exitted` event using `Async.AwaitEvent`:

```
let executeProcess (exe,cmdline) = async {
    let psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(exe,cmdline)  
    psi.UseShellExecute <- false 
    // [Lots of stuff omitted]
    p.BeginOutputReadLine() 
    let! _ = Async.AwaitEvent p.Exited
    return { exitCode = p.ExitCode
             stdout = output.ToString(); stderr = error.ToString() } }
```

This should unblock threads in the thread pool and so you'll be able to use `Async.Parallel` on all the URLs from the input array without any manual scheduling.

**EDIT** As @desco pointed out in a comment, the above is not quite right if the process exits before the `AwaitEvent` line is reached (before it may miss the event). To fix that, you need to use `Event.guard` function, which was discussed in this SO question:

- [Need help regarding Async and fsi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649161/need-help-regarding-async-and-fsi)

Comment: Async.AwaitEvent p.Exited can potentially hang forever if process will exit very quickly (basically before hte call to AwaitEvent)

Comment: I made the change that was suggested regarding changing the execute funtion but the return does not appear to capture the results from the command now. The search of the "exeout" converted to string does not appear to have the returns. It also runs runs so fast I do not believe its running the ping.exe now.

Comment: @desco - This was discussed here before, but I couldn't find the previous question. Thanks for reminding me - I added a link to the answer, which should explain how to fix that case.

Comment: @gear_9 I think you need to set `EnableRaisingEvents` property (see the related SO question that I just added to the answer).